# Javascript sort doesn't work when i'm using it from another function

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm new in Javascript and getting this weird issue:
When calling "bubbleSort" function from another "sort" function which supposed to clone the array and return a new sorted array - the result i get is not right.

I'll be happy to know what is the problem, I've been trying other ways to clone the array such as while loop, slice, [...a] and others and still can't understand what the problem is.

```js
function bubbleSort(arr, compareFunction = comparator()) {
  var len = arr.length;
  console.log("bubble!!");
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
      if (comparator(a[j], a[j + 1]) == 1) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
function sort(a, sorter, compareFunction = comparator()) {
  return sorter(a, comparator);
}
function sortNumbers(a) {
  var arrClone = a.slice(0);
  arrClone = sort(arrClone, bubbleSort);
  return arrClone;
}
function comparator(a, b) { if (a < b) return -1; else if (a > b) return 1; else return 0; }


// when i'm using any of the following:
var a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(bubbleSort(a));
a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(bubbleSort(a, comparator));
a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(sort(a, bubbleSort));
// I'm getting the desired result:
// [ 3, 9, 33, 103, 198, 200, 726, 764, 984 ]

// But when i'm using:

a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(sortNumbers(a));
// I'm getting:
// [ 33, 3, 103, 200, 726, 198, 984, 9, 764 ]
```

when i'm using any of the following:

```
var a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(bubbleSort(a));
console.log(bubbleSort(a, comparator));
console.log(sort(a, bubbleSort));
```

I'm getting the desired result:

```
 [ 3, 9, 33, 103, 198, 200, 726, 764, 984 ]
```

But when i'm using:

```
console.log(sortNumbers(a));
```

I'm getting:

```
[ 33, 3, 103, 200, 726, 198, 984, 9, 764 ]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming? Please *read* tag descriptions before adding them. People subscribe to different tags and would prefer not to have their feed clogged with stuff unrelated to their interests. I've removed the FP tag.

Comment: I don't see the issue either. `console.log(sortNumbers(a))` is getting the desired result on both Chrome and Safari for me.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to show what they are seeing. The problem is as I have in my answer and you do not see the problem if you run the sort over and over as it sorts in place and then the final "not working one" starts and ends with a sorted array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo where you are using `a` in place of the parameter `arr`, so when you `.slice`, your `arr` and `a` are not the same thing.

```
function bubbleSort(arr, compareFunction = comparator()) {
 //...
      if (comparator(a[j], a[j + 1]) == 1) {
 //...
}

var a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jacob Glad to help. Those kinds of typos are hard to spot.

Comment: Sounds like a typo-type question then. Should have been closed as such

Answer (score 1):

```
 function sort(a, sorter, compareFunction = comparator())
```

should be

```
 function sort(a, sorter, compareFunction = comparator)
```

cause you are passing a function, no a result.

moreover you are passing it but not using, anyway

Comment: While that does seem wrong, I don't see any problems with it not working as such because of this.